# Google カレンダーAPI についての質問です。

Tags: google-api

Google カレンダーAPI についての質問です。

Google カレンダーAPI　をphpで取得し、サービスアカウントを使用して予定を書き込みました。

再度、その同じカレンダーIDのカレンダーを読み込むと、サービスアカウントでphpから書き込んだ予定だけ、読み込むことができません。

原因はなにが考えられますか？

もしくは、サービスアカウントでphpから書き込まれた予定は、phpでは読み込めない仕様なのでしょうか？

設定情報
①google-api-php-client-1-master　の autoload.php を使っています。
②Google カレンダーV3 です。
③カレンダーID　では共有しているメールアカウント（サービスアカウント）には「予定の変更権限」を与えてあり、カレンダーに書き込みはできます。
④オーナーがGoogleカレンダー上で直接書き込んだ予定は、phpで読み込むことができますが、サービスアカウントでphpで書き込んだ予定は読み込むことができません。

要するに、phpで読み込んで、予定をphpで書き込んだ後、リロードしても予定をphpで書き込んだものだけ読み込めないという現象です。

なお、Google カレンダーを開くと、phpから書き込んだ予定は、しっかりと書きこまれています。

ただ、予定の作成者は、オーナーのメールアカウントではなく、サービスアカウントのアドレスで作成されています。

どなたかおわかりになる方はいらっしゃいませんでしょうか？

＊＊＊＊追記＊＊＊＊

```
//read EVENT
$json_path = '../json/XXXX-123465789.json';
$json_string = file_get_contents($json_path, true);
$json = json_decode($json_string, true);
$private_key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvQIBADAN・・・・・";
$client_email = "123456789-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
$scopes = array(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
$credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
  $client_email,
  $scopes,
  $private_key
);

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google Calendar PHP API");
$client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);


$read_start = mktime(0, 0, 0, 4, 10, 2017);
$read_end = mktime(0, 0, 0, 4, 17, 2017);

$calendarId = '123456789@group.calendar.google.com';
$optParams = array(
  'maxResults' => 99,
  'orderBy' => 'startTime',
  'singleEvents' => TRUE,
  'timeMin' => date('c', $read_start),
  'timeMax' => date('c', $read_end),
);

$results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);

//create EVENT

$json_path = './json/xxx-123456789.json';
$json_string = file_get_contents($json_path, true);
$json = json_decode($json_string, true);

$calendarId = '123456789@group.calendar.google.com';
$private_key = $json['private_key'];
$client_email = $json['client_email'];
$scopes = array(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
$credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
  $client_email,
  $scopes,
  $private_key
);

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google Calendar");
$client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);


$meeting_end_time = _get_sum_time($set_time,$meeting_time);
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' => 'created by service account',
  'start' => array(
     'dateTime' => '2017-04-04T00:12:00+09:00',
     'timeZone' => 'Asia/Tokyo',
  ),
  'end' => array(
      'dateTime' => '2017-04-04T00:13:00+09:00',
      'timeZone' => 'Asia/Tokyo',
  ),
));
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
```

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 書き込みを行ったときと結果を確認したときの具体的なコードを質問を編集し追記してください

Comment: マルチポスト　https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11173109741

Comment: @suzukis 様、コードを追記させていただきました。見ていただければ幸いです。よろしくお願いします。このコードでとくにエラーは起きません。

Comment: @Andy 上記コードの `$results` に入ってこない、という趣旨の質問だとすると、コードを見る限りでは、2017/04/04 にイベントを作成して、
`listEvents()` で 2017/04/10〜2017/04/17 の期間で取得しているのが問題なのではないでしょうか。

Comment: @quesera2 様　$results には、サービスアカウント以外のイベントは読み込むことができます。しかし、期間内にあるサービスアカウントで書き込まれたイベントは読み込むことができません。

Answer (score 1):

同じ問題にあたりました。繰り返しイベントを通常イベントにばらして取得するパラメータをtrueにしたら取得できるようになりました。